# What is the meaning of "<-" in JS

Tags: javascript

in the following code snippet I'd expect an error, but false is returned. Why?

```
foo = {}
foo <- "lel"
```

returns false

It certainly is not comparing which one is larger, so what is it doing?

Comment: Is foo less than the arithmetic complement of the numeric value of the string `"lel"` — it's the less-than operator and the unary negation operator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<-` doesn't mean anything as a single token. You have `<` (less than) followed by `-` (unary `-` = negation) applied to `"lel"`. E.g.:

```
foo < -"lel"
```

It's false because `-"lel"` is `NaN`*, and *all* comparisons with `NaN` are false (even equality, e.g. `NaN === NaN` is false).

(It happens that `foo` gets coerced to number by the `<` as well [that's what `<` and `>` do when one of the operands is of type number and the other isn't]. And that coercing `{}` to number *also* yields `NaN`. So the final step is `NaN < NaN` which is false because, again, all comparisons with `NaN` are false.)

---

* ...because applying a unary `-` or `+` to a string coerces that string to number; `"lel"` coerces to `NaN`, and then negating that gives you `NaN` because like comparisons, all math ops on `NaN` result in `NaN`.